# проблема в передачи значения минут текущего времени времени в анимацию угола поворота Canvas в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

понимаю, что возможно был уже такой вопрос, но я не могу найти ответа уже 2 дня. распишите поподробнее, пожалуйста. Вот xaml, куда на место To="{Binding Path=ProgressAngleProperty}" надо что-то вставить.

```
Canvas.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                            To="{Binding Path=ProgressAngleProperty}"
                            Duration="0:0:10"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Canvas.Triggers>
```

вот .cs, где проперти

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressAngleProperty =
                                    DependencyProperty.Register("ProgressAngle",
                                            typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow));
public int ProgressAngle
{
    get { return (int)this.GetValue(ProgressAngleProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ProgressAngleProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: А вы ошибки смотрели в логах, что появляется, что не работает и что ожидаете?

Comment: @Александр вы пишите свой контрол?

Comment: @Александр короче я могу долго не отвечать, но вот на затравку. DependencyProperty немного для другого используются. Посмотрите в сторону INPC и реализации MVVM паттерна(точнее парадигму и как его реализовать в WPF). Вам нужно посмотреть, как реализовать VM и как View данные получает.

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо большое за ответ, я, конечно, мало что понял, но сейчас посмотрю, спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ошибок вообще никаких нет, просто не работает, как ожидается. ожидается, что с изменением времени канвас будет вращаться.